# MySQL Round Trip import and export not the same

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, collation

I'm setting up a development environment for a content management system with a database backend.

The source for the dev environment is a virtual machine snapshot from production the target environment is a docker environment.

We have the application code under git source control, but also want to source control the database content. This will enable us to migrate both code and content all at once and know what we are changing.

I've written an import script and an export script.

Everything is working except for about 7 tables that won't roundtrip data. Each export and import loop the data is growing for some odd characters.

I have this data in an import statement

```
"Sparty’s\"
```

After importing it and re-exporting it it becomes this:

```
"Spartyâ€™s\"
```

Here are my character sets and collations:

```
SELECT DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME, DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'dbname';
+----------------------------+------------------------+
| DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME | DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME |
+----------------------------+------------------------+
| utf8                       | utf8_unicode_ci        |
+----------------------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is my export bash script

```
for x in `mysql --skip-column-names -u root -ppassword dbname -e 'show tables;'`; 
do
     echo exporting $x
     mysqldump -u root -ppassword --skip-add-drop-table --skip-add-locks --skip-disable-keys --skip-set-charset --default-character-set=utf8 --extended-insert=FALSE --replace --skip-dump-date dbname $x > "/var/db/$x.sql"
done
```

Here is my import statement

```
service mysql start 
for x in `ls /var/db/*.sql`; do
     echo importing $x
     mysql -ppassword dbname --default-character-set=utf8 --force < $x
done
```

I feel the problem is in the import because the data looks correct when I'm importing it, but I'm not sure what is up...

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';                   
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

The column meta on this table is one of the seven tables giving me trouble.

```
show create table cms_form_field;
+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table          | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| cms_form_field | CREATE TABLE `cms_form_field` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `form_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `label` text NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `order_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `meta` text NOT NULL,
  `update_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `update_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=314 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trying to figure out what was going on I finally solved the issue.

The issue in my particular case was that the import statement I was using for test:

```
mysql -ppassword dbname --default-character-set=utf8 --force < ./db/tablename.sql
```

Was different from my scripted import.

```
mysql -ppassword dbname --force < ./db/tablename.sql
```

How I figured it out was by viewing the binary at each stage in the process to ensure it was what I expected.

First, the way I discovered there were discrepancies in the first place was by using git.

By adding my sql file to git `git add utf8.sql` then when I do an export I can do `git status` and `git diff --word-diff=color` to see if the data changed.

Using this method I isolated one table, then one row, and then one character that was failing to use as my test case.

The rest of these steps focus on ensuring that character is right.

How to find the character. Look in your data. In my case I had "Sparty’s\" that would look incorrect after export and import. By using a hex viewer (discussed below) I used the y and s characters as the endpoints and looked at what was in the middle to determine the character.

Starting with the database. I would select the one column from the one row with the issue as hex like this:

```
hex(meta) from cms_form_field where id = 187;
```

I would paste the hex result from the buffer into a text tool (Sublime in my case)

```
613A323A7B733A31323A226669656C645F76616C756573223B613A31333A7B733A363A2244696E696E67223B733A363A2244696E696E67223B733A31303A22537061727479C3A2E282ACE284A273
```

That string above is this text:

```
a:2:{s:12:"field_values";a:13:{s:6:"Dining";s:6:"Dining";s:10:"SpartyÃ¢â‚¬â„¢s
```

After pasting the hex text into Sublime I would search for `79` and see what characters were next. If it was `E28099` I was in good shape, time to move on to the next step of the process.

In the above example it is not the character i'm expecting (`E28099`) instead it is `C3A2E282ACE284A2`. This means the data is bad in the database.

After ensuring the data is correct in the database the next place it goes is the filesystem.

I used vim to follow a similar process to verify the character is what I need: `E28099`

First I export the data to a file on disk:

```
mysqldump -u root -ppassword --skip-add-drop-table --skip-add-locks --skip-disable-keys --skip-set-charset --default-character-set=utf8 --replace --skip-dump-date dbname  > "./utf8.sql"
```

Then I needed a hex viewer. Sublime has one, but it didn't work well (search was input in hex and didn't seem to search the whole buffer for me, and I had to have another window open to help me compare the expected text to) so I used vim. To put vim in hex mode I used the command `:%!xxd` after opening utf8.sql.

Vim is nice because it shows the hex on the left and unicode on the right. Additionally allows searching by unicode! So I can input my search term `Sparty` and quickly see the next character, looking for `E28099`. If I didn't see `E28099` and in the previous step it was `E28099` then that means the problem was with the export.

This is what the line looks like in vim

```
000a650: 3a31 303a 5c22 5370 6172 7479 e280 9973  :10:\"Sparty...s
```

I copy paste that line into Sublime to do my manual character comparison. This isn't necessary, but I'm not good at reading hex so it helps.

```
3a31 303a 5c22 5370 6172 7479 e280 9973  :10:\"Sparty...s
: 1  0 :  \ "  S p  a r  t y  ’      s 
these markers delinate the    |     |
character ’ character I'm     |     |
looking for (3 bytes)         |     |
```

Other things that helped:
In mysql doing `select hex('y');` shows me the

```
+----------+
| hex('y') |
+----------+
| 79       |
+----------+
```

To get the reverse I can do `select X'79';`

```
+-------+
| X'79' |
+-------+
| y     |
+-------+
```

In my case this was useful for dealing with `select X'E28099';` although I couldn't paste `select hex('’');` into my sql terminal (however it worked from save command files)

Answer (score 1):

You had `latin1` somewhere.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831 .  Do...

- the `SELECT HEX ...` to see whether you have the correct utf8 encoding: `E28099`.
- `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see what `CHARACTER SET` that column has.
- `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` to see what the connection is like.

Read about Mojibake.

Comment: Thanks! Yes when I do select hex(meta) I see E28099 where the ’ characters are. I updated the question to include the show create table and show variables like - everything looks utf8. I read over the linked answer, but I'm not sure what the fix is ( sounds like everything should be working?) or are they saying I need to edit the data (painful - unless there is an automated way?) Thanks again!

Comment: sounds like it is a double encoding issue?

Comment: When I do this: select hex(convert(meta using latin1)) from cms_form_field where id = 187; instead of E28099 I get 92

Comment: Looking at my original db backup I see the value is 3f. I have a feeling this is a problem since it is not 92 - and apparently 3f is ?. However it seems to get to the correct value somehow... or maybe I'm reading things wrong (display vs. underlying storage...) *sigh*

Comment: OK per my previous comment, it was a display issue *doh*. It is actually 92 on the disk export. I think if I can figure out how to get that to be E28099 I'll be all set.

Comment: Thanks for your help Rick. I had a couple of issues - my first export was bad and then I wasn't using the import statement I thought  I was. I had stripped out a lot of info from my initial question to try and simplify things. I think that was a mistake.

Comment: `92` is latin1 encoding; `E28099` is utf8 encoding.  Note that your `SELECT` explicitly converted to latin1; so it is not telling you what bytes are actually stored.  `3f` is `?`, meaning charset troubles.

Comment: If the export has `92`, then the import should state that the data coming in is `latin1`.  (No need to change anything else; MySQL will convert to utf8 if the column is declared utf8.)